Dynamic SQL created with array of values
I have a list of column names, for example ('Name', 'Code', 'Title') that can be array but not necessarily, it can be anything. I just have a list of column names.
Then I have to create a dynamic SQL select that has to be executed later. That dynamic SQL select is generating XML, so it uses for xml path, here is a simplified version:
@sql = select @column_name, some_fixed_column
       from t_table
       where some_Condition
       for xml path;

this has to be dynamic query plus it creates XML, but I want to make it somehow go through all column names from the list, so the general outcome would be something like:
select Name, some_fixed_column from tb_table where some_Condition for xml path;
select Code, some_fixed_column from tb_table where some_Condition for xml path;
select Title, some_fixed_column from tb_table where some_Condition for xml path;

I can't even use + or Union because it doesn't work with for xml path queries (I tried). The query is quite complicated and it already works on multiple XML levels.
Is this even possible?

You can create a loop through all the columns you want to be dynamic and create/run each statement in the loop as you loop through.  You can create dynamic SQL but you have to put single quotes around it.  Then for the variable you have to use +.  Short something like this SQL = 'Select ' + @column_name + ' rest of your dynamic code '   Then execute the sql variable

You can use UNPIVOT to generate multiple rows, either by the UNPIVOT operator or by a CROSS APPLY VALUES construct

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
